# Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC1 brokes submit button?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Laravel 4 and Twitter Bootstrap 3 to make a simple application, but I have hit something strange when dealing with my forms. I was using an earlier CSS/HTML template system and the submit button worked fine, but now it's entirely unresponsive. I have used the same Laravel Blade code for my form, so I can't figure out why the form refuses to submit.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <h1>Event Selection</h1>
        {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'TicketController@postIndex')) }}                               
            <div class="form-group">
                <select id="eventSelect" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($events as $event)
                        <option value='{{$event->eventID}}'>{{ $event->eventName }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="buttonsub" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Continue</button>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Full code posted here: https://gist.github.com/verkaufer/6ac3aaf3475cc67c3b96

Is this a Laravel 4 issue or am I just running into something quirky because Twitter Bootstrap 3 is in RC stage?

Comment: I am also using Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC1 + Laravel 4, and I have no problem with any submit button, I have some 20 forms.

Comment: Change the type attribute from `type=button` to `type=submit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of your button is: *button*, no *submit*. Try changing the type from `button` to `submit`.

You need to change from:

```
<button type="button" id="buttonsub" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Continue</button>
```

To this:

```
<button type="submit" id="buttonsub" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Continue</button>
```

Remember that using the right type attribute is quite important. Sometimes it could be for semantic reasons, and sometimes it could for functionality reasons.